# Create a review between two tags in Atlassian Crucible using REST API

Tags: git, rest, atlassian-fisheye, atlassian-crucible, eyeql

I want to have an automated way to create a review in crucible between two Git tags. (I also have FishEye which allows browsing the code).

I can do it via the web by doing the following:

Create Review -> Search for files -> Advanced Search
EyeQL query:

```
select revisions from dir "/" where between tags (starttag,endtag] 
group by changeset return path, revision, author, date, csid
```

and clicking the box saying "Add all n revisions" 
(That may not be the most efficient route, but it works)

However I cannot find a way to do the same process via the rest API.

I'm able to create a review using the REST API but the next step (specifying which files to review) escapes me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - use `git rev-list starttag..endtag` to get a list of all revisions between the two, and then use [this API](https://docs.atlassian.com/fisheye-crucible/latest/wadl/crucible.html#rest-service:reviews-v1:id:addChangeset) to add all the changesets individually.